# How to add margin between feedback stars?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to add space between feedback stars(e.g. 15px).There are two things to consider I have to add margin not only to the grey star(background image), but to the gold one too(i element). How can I achieve this tried `margin-left` , but no luck, the images are svg, maybe I should add some space in the image, but that seems like a very primitive idea, any suggestions?

```css
.star-rating {
  font-size: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 250px;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  background: url('greyStar.svg');
  background-size: contain;
}

.star-rating i {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
  z-index: 1;
  background: url('goldenStar.svg');
  background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<span class="star-rating">
    <a href="">
        <input type="radio" name="rating" value="1" id='input1'>
        <i></i>
    </a>
    
    <a href="">
        <input type="radio" name="rating" value="2" id='input2' >
     <i></i>
    </a>
</div>
```

Here is the full example: http://codepen.io/nikasv/pen/dMWgrZ

Comment: I think you need to different approach for this work.

Comment: I wasn't able to add margins to your example, but here's another way of achieving this star rating effect (with margins) with CSS (using flexbox): http://codepen.io/FullR/pen/YqQgQL?editors=1100

Comment: In your example the stars are not clickable. You cannot make a choice :/

Comment: @Mamboleoo Ah. Yeah I just realized that's a feature

Comment: @Mamboleoo I've fixed my code to allow for clicking

Comment: @Mamboleoo I forgot to point that out, yes it is a feature. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I think changing the `background-size` to numeric percentages is more what you want, since you will not change anything at the html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to adapt the background sizes for both elements

```css
.star-rating {
  font-size: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 400px;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  background:url('http://imgh.us/greyStar.svg');
  background-size: 20% 100%;
}
.star-rating input {
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  opacity: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
}
.star-rating i {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
  z-index: 1;
  background:url('http://imgh.us/goldenStar.svg');  
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
.star-rating input:hover + i,
.star-rating input:checked + i {
  opacity: 1;
}
.star-rating #input2 + i {
  width: 40%;
  background-size: 50% 100%;
}
.star-rating #input3 + i {
  width: 60%;
  background-size: 33% 100%;
}
.star-rating #input4 + i {
  width: 80%;
  background-size: 25% 100%;
}
.star-rating #input5 + i {
  width: 100%;
  background-size: 20% 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="star-rating">
     <a href="">
      <input type="radio" name="rating" value="1" id='input1'>
        <i></i>
     </a>

     <a href="">
      <input type="radio" name="rating" value="2" id='input2' >
        <i></i>
     </a>

     <a href="">
      <input type="radio" name="rating" value="3" id='input3'>
        <i></i>
     </a>

     <a href="">
      <input type="radio" name="rating" value="4" id='input4'>
        <i></i>
     </a>

     <a href="">
      <input type="radio" name="rating" value="5" id='input5'>
        <i></i>
     </a>
  </div>
```

Comment: There was no actual need to change the html, but your solution was almost the same as mine (except that you used % instead of px)

Comment: @GiovanniPerillo yes, we answered almost the same and almost at the same time. But I didn't change the HTML, it's a copy from the codepen in the question. Also, I think that you need to adjust also something in the *i* elements, your solution seems to fail in the hover state...

Comment: @vals thanks work great just a little addition, third star is a little bit off when hovered, `.star-rating #input3 + i{width: 60%;
  background-size: 33.5% 100%;}` works great.

Comment: Yes, you are right. To be more precise, it should be 33.33%. In modern browsers, you can set it to  calc(100% / 3). Happy that it helped :-)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using `input`s, `label`s, and flexbox:

```css
.star-rating {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.star-radio {
  display: none;
}

.star {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-image: url('http://imgh.us/greyStar.svg');
  background-size: contain;
  margin-left: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.star:hover,
.star-radio:checked + .star,
.star-radio:checked ~ .star,
.star:hover ~ .star {
  background-image: url('http://imgh.us/goldenStar.svg');
}
```

```html
<div class="star-rating">
  <input class="star-radio" id="star-1" type="radio" name="stars"/>
  <label for="star-1" class="star"></label>
  <input class="star-radio" id="star-2" type="radio" name="stars"/>
  <label for="star-2" class="star"></label>
  <input class="star-radio" id="star-3" type="radio" name="stars"/>
  <label for="star-3" class="star"></label>
  <input class="star-radio" id="star-4" type="radio" name="stars"/>
  <label for="star-4" class="star"></label>
  <input class="star-radio" id="star-5" type="radio" name="stars"/>
  <label for="star-5" class="star"></label>
</div>
```

CodePen: http://codepen.io/FullR/pen/YqQgQL?editors=1100

Comment: Thanks, works great, have to look more into 
 flex-direction: row-reverse;
  justify-content: flex-end; and see how it changes things :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different solution. I had to change your HTML because you can't add margin when you're using a repeating background.

In this example I'mu using `label` instead of links like you did. 
Now each label has a specific size and has it's own background. It's no more a repeating background.

If you're using a CSS Preprocessor you could use a `loop` to keep your CSS cleaner :)

Check it here : http://codepen.io/Mamboleoo/pen/JXJzJy

Don't hesitate if you have any question !

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `background-size`, it's the easier solution for your case.

Just add `background-size: 20% 100%;` to your css, where the first value is the width and the second is the height.

And don't forget to change the width of your `.star-rating` to the new value (in the case, I used `400px`)

I just added 6 lines of code and changed one. Here how it should looks like:

```
.star-rating {
  font-size: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 400px;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  background:url('http://imgh.us/greyStar.svg');
  background-size: 20% 100%;

}
.star-rating input {
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  opacity: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
}
.star-rating i {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
  z-index: 1;
  background:url('http://imgh.us/goldenStar.svg');  
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
.star-rating input:hover + i,
.star-rating input:checked + i {
  opacity: 1;
}
.star-rating #input2 + i {
  width: 40%;
  background-size: 50% 100%;
}
.star-rating #input3 + i {
  width: 60%;
  background-size: 33.4% 100%;
}
.star-rating #input4 + i {
  width: 80%;
  background-size: 25% 100%;
}
.star-rating #input5 + i {
  width: 100%;
  background-size: 20% 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this, [Example on codepen](http://codepen.io/o0nico0o/pen/EKXMLX)

HTML

```
<div class="star star-1"></div>
<div class="star star-2"></div>
<div class="star star-3"></div>
<div class="star star-4"></div>
<div class="star star-5"></div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.2.min.js"></script>
```

CSS

```
.star{
    background:url('http://imgh.us/greyStar.svg') no-repeat;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background-size:50px 50px;
    float:left;
    padding:0 10px;
}

.star-hover{
    background:url('http://imgh.us/goldenStar.svg') no-repeat; 
    background-size:50px 50px;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function() {     
    $('.star-1').hover(function(){
        $('.star-1').toggleClass('star-hover');    
    });
    $('.star-2').hover(function(){
        $('.star-1, .star-2').toggleClass('star-hover');    
    });
    $('.star-3').hover(function(){
        $('.star-1, .star-2, .star-3').toggleClass('star-hover');    
    });
    $('.star-4').hover(function(){
        $('.star-1, .star-2, .star-3, .star-4').toggleClass('star-hover');    
    });
    $('.star-5').hover(function(){
        $('.star-1, .star-2, .star-3, .star-4, .star-5').toggleClass('star-hover');    
    });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {     
    $('.star-1').hover(function(){                 $('.star-1').toggleClass('star-hover');    
    });
    $('.star-2').hover(function(){                 $('.star-1, .star-2').toggleClass('star-hover');    
    });
    $('.star-3').hover(function(){                 $('.star-1, .star-2, .star-3').toggleClass('star-hover');    
    });
    $('.star-4').hover(function(){                 $('.star-1, .star-2, .star-3, .star-4').toggleClass('star-hover');    
    });
    $('.star-5').hover(function(){                 $('.star-1, .star-2, .star-3, .star-4, .star-5').toggleClass('star-hover');    
    });
});
```

```css
.star{
background:url('http://imgh.us/greyStar.svg') no-repeat;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background-size:50px 50px;
  float:left;
  padding:0 10px;
}

.star-hover{
 background:url('http://imgh.us/goldenStar.svg') no-repeat; 
  background-size:50px 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="star star-1"></div>
<div class="star star-2"></div>
<div class="star star-3"></div>
<div class="star star-4"></div>
<div class="star star-5"></div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.2.min.js"></script>
```